# Handle POST request with Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I am using fulcrum to collect data. fulcrum has a [webhook feature](https://learn.fulcrumapp.com/dev/webhooks)

I have created a firebase function and linked the firebase function to fulcrums webhook feature with the functions URL. `https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/fulcrumHook`

**Here is my existing function.**

```
exports.fulcrumHook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log(response.data.form_id)
  response.send(200)
})
```

Through hours of debugging, in the logs I can see that the data I want is coming through but I am struggling to access it in the function itself.

When I log the request I get `IncomingMessage { _readableState: ReadableState { objectMode: false,.....`

When I log the response I get `ServerResponse { domain: null, _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [ [....` as well as the body much further down with the actual data i need in it.

I have search for all the keywords i can think of about how to handle this data but I am completely stumped.

Do I need to handle the response like a promise with `response.then(data => ...stuff)`

Do I need to establish a connection like a socket with `response.on('data', (data) => ...stuff)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is in the [documentation for HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

The request and response are essentially Express Request and Response objects.

> Used as arguments for `onRequest()`, the [Request](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client, and the [Response](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) object gives you a way to send a response back to the client.

You can click through to those linked APIs to understand in detail how they work.

Data passed to the function can be found by [reading values from the request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request).  If it's a POST request, form values are read like this:

```
request.body.form_id
```

The response is sent using `response.send()`.  Just pass it an object that will get automatically serialized as JSON.  Or use the linked API for the response object from above to learn more about your options.

Comment: i'v never been happier to see the number 200. Thank you for your explanation (: